# Problem booting from USB stick on Lenovo Thinkpad x100e

Tags: thinkpad

Purchased x100e today and spent several hours trying to get it boot from the USB stick. Unfortunately, no luck — getting “Operating System not found” message. Have tested the stick with another computer — boots perfectly.

BIOS boot sequence has USB HDD as the first entry followed by USB FDD and USB CD-ROM.

For some reason the USB HDD entry is pre-pended with a dash: -USB HDD.

Also, changing the Controller Mode Option value as suggested [here](http://thinkpad-x100e.blogspot.com/2010/05/installing-ubuntu-910-karmic-koala-64.html) did not make any difference.

Any suggestions? Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have tried a different USB stick -- it worked.

Just to clarify:

- The original USB stick Corsair Voyager 2Gb, that I was having problem with, was recognised by the BIOS per se (it was listed during the BIOS diagnostics), but was not recognised as a bootable device (was not in the list of bootable devices at all).
- The stick that worked is Corsair Voyager 16Gb.

Both USB sticks have been formated and made bootable using usb-creator under Ubuntu 9.10.